# gdal2tiles_parallel seems to be signiciantly slowing down for super high-res images

Tags: python, gdal, tiles

I have 3 images that I've been trying to 'tileize'

- 1 86,000*41,000
- 2 86,000*21,000

both are simple .pngs

I've been using the [parallel version of gdal2tiles](https://github.com/GitHubRGI/geopackage-python/blob/master/Tiling/gdal2tiles_parallel.py) on a DigitalOcean box with 20cores and 64GB of Ram(Ubuntu 14.04 x64) with the package gdal-pin installed.

Whenever I try and tileize the images with the command

```
python gdal2tiles_parallel.py -v -p raster -k Something.vrt -z 1-7 -r lanczos
```

it starts off fine but then after a minute or two it just grinds to slower than dial-up snail speed. A few images a minute. Is there a configuration option I'm missing or is the image simply too big? The ones I'm going to be processing are 800mb to 1.5gb.

Comment: Dumb question: did you look at GDAL options to allocate more memory e.g https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions ?

Comment: Didn't see that config (new to it) let me give it a shot with that parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I have been experiencing this issue when trying to convert a 86400x33600 raster into tiles (zoom 0-10) with the gdal2tiles_parallel.py script. I think I have found a way to prevent the slowdown, though it doesn't explain why it occurred in the first place.

I initially would try to run with the following command. The script would output ~15k files (~50MB) in mere minutes then slow down to a a few files a minute despite showing all processors running at capacity. The slowdown would predictably occur every time I would restart the script.

This is the command I used that would slow down:

```
python gdal2tiles_parallel.py -w all -k -z 0-10 -a 255 myinput.vrt myoutput
```

**I found that removing the arguments for metadata outputs such as *-w all* and *-k* (for web and KML respectively) seem to fix the slowdown.**

Thus, the script runs at a faster and consistent speed with the following command:

```
python gdal2tiles_parallel.py -z 0-10 -a 255 myinput.vrt myoutput
```

This workaround has the side-effect of not generating the web and kml files that are ordinarily generated by gdal2tiles, which you you may still want to use to view your tiled overlay. Simply copying the html files from another run gdal2tiles_parallel over a subset to the new folder worked for me. You may have to edit the html code to alter the min-max zoom levels to accommodate your new tiles. I do not think that this copy-paste solution works for the KML however.